# Image dimensions max size jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery validation plugin to validate images. I have a validation requirement where images must be greater than 250px by 250px, if the images are not then the plugin will throw an error. Here's the code for the min image size function:

```
$.validator.addMethod('minImageSize', function(value, element, minSize) {
          var imageSize = $(element).data('imageSize');
          return (imageSize) && (imageSize.width >= minSize.width) && (imageSize.height >= minSize.height);
        }, function(minSize, element) {
          return ($(element).data('imageSize')) ? ("Your image's size must be at least " + minSize.width + "px by " + minSize.height + "px") : "Selected file is not an image.";
        });
```

Is there a way to create a maxSize function? Where if the user uploads an image that is greater than the specified sizes, it'll throw an error? Let's say the max image size is 6000px by 6000px, if the user uploads something greater than that it will throw an error.

Comment: If the `minImageSize` rule is working, then you simply need to change the comparison operators around a little bit and check against new parameters... have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to create a maxSize function? Where if the user uploads an image that is greater than the specified sizes, it'll throw an error?*

If your `minImageSize` method works, then a slight modification to create a `maxImageSize` method seems trivial...

```
$.validator.addMethod('maxImageSize', function(value, element, maxSize) {
    var imageSize = $(element).data('imageSize');
    return (imageSize) && (imageSize.width < maxSize.width) && (imageSize.height < maxSize.height);
    }, function(maxSize, element) {
        return ($(element).data('imageSize')) ? ("Your image's size must be less than " + maxSize.width + "px by " + maxSize.height + "px") : "Selected file is not an image.";
    }
);
```